# Create a new factor level (new row) based on data from other rows with conditional statements

Tags: r, if-statement, row

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0002", "0005", "0005" ,"0009" ,"0009" ,"0018", "0018" ,"0039" ,"0039" , "0043" ,"0043", "0046", "0046" ,"0048" ,"0048"),
                 Timepoint= c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B",  "A", "B",  "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 A = c(NA , 977.146 , NA , 964.315 ,NA , 952.311 , NA , 950.797 , 947.465 , 902.852 ,  985.124  ,NA , 930.141 ,1007.790 , 1027.110 , 999.414),
                 B = c(998.988 , NA , 998.680 , NA , 1020.560 ,  955.540 , 911.606 , 964.039   ,  988.087 , 902.367 , 959.338 ,1029.050 , 987.374 ,1066.400  ,957.512 , 917.597),
                 C = c( 987.140 , 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 969.469 , 943.398  ,936.034,  965.292 , 996.404 , 920.610 , 967.047, 913.517 , 893.428 , 921.606 , 929.590  ,950.493), 
                 D = c( 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 1005.820 , 925.752 , 969.469  ,943.398 ,  965.292 , 996.404 ,  967.047 ,  NA , 893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , 929.590 , 950.493),
                 E = c(1006.330, 1028.070 ,  954.274 ,1005.910  ,949.969 , 992.820 ,934.407 , 948.913 ,    961.375  ,955.296 , 961.128  ,998.119 ,1009.110 , 994.891 ,1000.170  ,982.763),
                 G= c(NA , 958.990 , 924.680 , 955.927 , NA , 949.384  ,973.348 , 984.392 , 943.894 , 961.468 , 995.368 , 994.997 ,  979.454 , 952.605 ,NA , 956.507), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Based on this dataframe, I need to create an extra FACTOR level for the variable (`df$TimePoint`) that will be filled based on the following conditions - we have already factors `A` and `B` in that variable so lets say that we want to create factor level `X` :

- For `df$A`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >999 then the factor X will be filled with the same value as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise (if it is ≤999) then it will be filled with the value at df$timepoint A.
- For `df$B`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >986, factor X will be == as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise X will == df$timepoint A.
- For `df$C`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >1000, factor X will be == as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise X will == df$timepoint A.
- For `df$D`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >1030, factor X will be == as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise X will == df$timepoint A.
- For `df$E`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >800, factor X will be == as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise X will == df$timepoint A.
- For `df$G`. If `df$Timepoint` B is >950, factor X will be == as df$Timepoint level B value, otherwise X will == df$timepoint A.

The new dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one tidyverse approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint,
              values_from = A:G
              ) %>% 
  mutate(A_X = ifelse(A_B > 999, A_B, A_A),
         B_X = ifelse(B_B > 986, B_B, B_A),
         C_X = ifelse(C_B > 1000, C_B, C_A),
         D_X = ifelse(D_B > 1030, D_B, D_A),
         E_X = ifelse(E_B > 800, E_B, E_A),
         G_X = ifelse(G_B > 950, G_B, G_A)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = A_A:G_X,
               names_sep = "_",
               names_to = c("cat","Timepoint")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = cat,
              values_from = value)

#> # A tibble: 24 x 8
#>    PatientID Timepoint     A     B     C     D     E     G
#>    <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0002      A           NA   999.  987.  962. 1006.   NA 
#>  2 0002      B          977.   NA   962.  929. 1028.  959.
#>  3 0002      X           NA    NA   987.  962. 1028.  959.
#>  4 0005      A           NA   999.  929.  978.  954.  925.
#>  5 0005      B          964.   NA   978. 1006. 1006.  956.
#>  6 0005      X           NA    NA   929.  978. 1006.  956.
#>  7 0009      A           NA  1021.  969.  926.  950.   NA 
#>  8 0009      B          952.  956.  943.  969.  993.  949.
#>  9 0009      X           NA  1021.  969.  926.  993.   NA 
#> 10 0018      A           NA   912.  936.  943.  934.  973.
#> 11 0018      B          951.  964.  965.  965.  949.  984.
#> 12 0018      X           NA   912.  936.  943.  949.  984.
#> 13 0039      A          947.  988.  996.  996.  961.  944.
#> 14 0039      B          903.  902.  921.  967.  955.  961.
#> 15 0039      X          947.  988.  996.  996.  955.  961.
#> 16 0043      A          985.  959.  967.   NA   961.  995.
#> 17 0043      B           NA  1029.  914.  893.  998.  995.
#> 18 0043      X           NA  1029.  967.   NA   998.  995.
#> 19 0046      A          930.  987.  893.  922. 1009.  979.
#> 20 0046      B         1008. 1066.  922.  976.  995.  953.
#> 21 0046      X         1008. 1066.  893.  922.  995.  953.
#> 22 0048      A         1027.  958.  930.  930. 1000.   NA 
#> 23 0048      B          999.  918.  950.  950.  983.  957.
#> 24 0048      X          999.  958.  930.  930.  983.  957.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And here is an alternative using `group_modify` and `add_row`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>% 
  group_modify(.f =
                 
    ~ {
      df_b <- .x[.x$Timepoint == "B",]
      df_a <- .x[.x$Timepoint == "A",]
      
      .x %>% add_row(Timepoint = "X",
                     A = ifelse(df_b$A >  999, df_b$A, df_a$A),
                     B = ifelse(df_b$B >  986, df_b$B, df_a$B),
                     C = ifelse(df_b$C > 1000, df_b$C, df_a$C),
                     D = ifelse(df_b$D > 1030, df_b$D, df_a$D),
                     E = ifelse(df_b$E >  800, df_b$E, df_a$E),
                     G = ifelse(df_b$G >  950, df_b$G, df_a$G)
                     )
    })

#> # A tibble: 24 x 8
#> # Groups:   PatientID [8]
#>    PatientID Timepoint     A     B     C     D     E     G
#>    <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0002      A           NA   999.  987.  962. 1006.   NA 
#>  2 0002      B          977.   NA   962.  929. 1028.  959.
#>  3 0002      X           NA    NA   987.  962. 1028.  959.
#>  4 0005      A           NA   999.  929.  978.  954.  925.
#>  5 0005      B          964.   NA   978. 1006. 1006.  956.
#>  6 0005      X           NA    NA   929.  978. 1006.  956.
#>  7 0009      A           NA  1021.  969.  926.  950.   NA 
#>  8 0009      B          952.  956.  943.  969.  993.  949.
#>  9 0009      X           NA  1021.  969.  926.  993.   NA 
#> 10 0018      A           NA   912.  936.  943.  934.  973.
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
rbind(df, df %>%
  mutate(X1 = ifelse(A > 999, A, lag(A))) %>% 
  mutate(X2 = ifelse(B > 986, B, lag(B))) %>%
  mutate(X3 = ifelse(C > 1000, C, lag(C))) %>%
  mutate(X4 = ifelse(D > 1030, D, lag(D))) %>%
  mutate(X5 = ifelse(E > 800, E, lag(E))) %>%
  mutate(X6 = ifelse(G > 950, G, lag(G))) %>% 
  filter(Timepoint == 'B') %>%
  select(PatientID, Timepoint, X1:X6) %>% 
  rename(A = X1,
         B = X2,
         C = X3,
         D = X4,
         E = X5,
         G = X6) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = 'X')) %>% 
  arrange(PatientID, Timepoint)
```

Output:

```
   PatientID Timepoint        A        B       C        D        E       G
1       0002         A       NA  998.988 987.140  961.810 1006.330      NA
2       0002         B  977.146       NA 961.810  929.466 1028.070 958.990
3       0002         X       NA       NA 987.140  961.810 1028.070 958.990
4       0005         A       NA  998.680 929.466  978.166  954.274 924.680
5       0005         B  964.315       NA 978.166 1005.820 1005.910 955.927
6       0005         X       NA       NA 929.466  978.166 1005.910 955.927
7       0009         A       NA 1020.560 969.469  925.752  949.969      NA
8       0009         B  952.311  955.540 943.398  969.469  992.820 949.384
9       0009         X       NA 1020.560 969.469  925.752  992.820      NA
10      0018         A       NA  911.606 936.034  943.398  934.407 973.348
11      0018         B  950.797  964.039 965.292  965.292  948.913 984.392
12      0018         X       NA  911.606 936.034  943.398  948.913 984.392
13      0039         A  947.465  988.087 996.404  996.404  961.375 943.894
14      0039         B  902.852  902.367 920.610  967.047  955.296 961.468
15      0039         X  947.465  988.087 996.404  996.404  955.296 961.468
16      0043         A  985.124  959.338 967.047       NA  961.128 995.368
17      0043         B       NA 1029.050 913.517  893.428  998.119 994.997
18      0043         X       NA 1029.050 967.047       NA  998.119 994.997
19      0046         A  930.141  987.374 893.428  921.606 1009.110 979.454
20      0046         B 1007.790 1066.400 921.606  976.192  994.891 952.605
21      0046         X 1007.790 1066.400 893.428  921.606  994.891 952.605
22      0048         A 1027.110  957.512 929.590  929.590 1000.170      NA
23      0048         B  999.414  917.597 950.493  950.493  982.763 956.507
24      0048         X  999.414  957.512 929.590  929.590  982.763 956.507
```